# Is it possible to run CQL3 queries "create table", "insert into" with Astyanax?

Tags: astyanax

For now I have found just "select" examples.

Or is it possible to do with e.g. MutationBatch?

```
MutationBatch m = keyspace.prepareMutationBatch();
ColumnListMutation<String> cfmStandard = m.withRow(MY_CF, ...);
```

my column family is:

```
 CREATE TABLE my_cf (
                   ... key text,
                   ... timeid timeuuid,
                   ...   flag boolean,
                   ...   data text,
                   ... PRIMARY KEY (key, timeid));
```

Comment: Astyanax forewer!! got inserts working with this: `CqlResult<String, String> cqlResult = keyspace.prepareQuery(MY_CF).withCql(insertBuilder.toString()).execute().getResult();` And will try to do create table, but unlikely this will work...

Comment: create table worked the same way ) Apologies to astyanax guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

worked for inserts and create:

```
keyspace.prepareQuery(MY_CF).withCql(queryBuilder.toString()).execute();
```